# Can a div using a clip path cut into another div?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

What I'm trying to create is a div that cuts into two other divs (one above, and one below, see picture below)

First I had no idea how to create a shape like that in css until I discovered `clip path: polygon`. Now I can sort of get the shape going when using a shape generator, but the problem is I can't get the div to cut into the other places. I tried to use a z-index but that didn't work.

I know I can use a negative margin to move the div more into the hero image but the polygon doesn't come out right.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3jxvha5/) I tried to add a snippet but was giving me too many issues, figured this would be easier and cleaner to see.

The HTML/CSS in particular is this:

```
<section class="ThreeSteps">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Decide</h2>
          <p>Pick</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Fundraise</h2>
          <p>We</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Celebrate</h2>
          <p>Give</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


.ThreeSteps {
  margin-top: -20px;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 325px,1689px 491px,1688px -466px,1px 82px);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 325px,1689px 491px,1688px -466px,1px 82px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what I should do? Thank you for your time.

[image: Div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that Clip Path just creates a mask on images. I think a better approach should be you create a pseudo-class :before and :after; positioning them absolute to the .ThreeSteps div.

something like this:

```
.ThreeSteps {
position: relative;
/*Other Stuffs*/
}

.ThreeSteps::before {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -115px;
left: 0;
background: url('my-triangle-image-top.svg') no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
z-index: 2000;
}

.ThreeSteps::after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: -115px;
background: url('my-triangle-image-bottom.svg') no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
z-index: 2000;
}
```

If you can use some Vector Image Editor (Like Adobe Illustrator), you can save a triangle image as 'my-triangle-image.svg', and use as a background image on pseudo-classes :before and :after . If you cant, just use a .png image, but svg is the best for this purpose.

Comment: Interesting, didn't think about using svg! thanks Bruno I'll give it a shot!